# Prevent change event from firing on checkbox after page reload

Tags: javascript

Each time I refresh the page the change event is fired on the checkbox. How to I prevent this from happening?

I have a standard checkbox in the form:

```
<div class="toggle-icon"><input id="this-box" class="toggle-icons" type="checkbox">
    <label for="this-box"><img class="toggle-image" width="36px" height="36px" src="/somedirectory/"></label>
</div>
```

In the javascript I have the change handler for the checkbox:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#this-box').change(function(e){
       //some actions I do not want to occur on page refresh
      });
    });
```

Appreciate the solutions people have posted, however there may be another issue with the code. Unfortunately cannot post greater-code-base here.

Comment: Based on this code, that shouldn't be firing on load unless something else on the page is causing the change.  Put a debugger stop inside the binding and see if you can follow the stack trace to find what is causing the binding to fire.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I think I need to do more research into what's going on.

Comment: You want to fix that issue first if possible.  If you can't fix that (e.g. it is in code you don't have access to) then you could work around it but it is a bit hackish.  Set a global boolean `var isFirstRun = true` and then check it inside the binding, `if(isFirstRun){isFirstRun = false; return false;}`.  This way the first time it gets fired you just flip the boolean and exit out, ever time after it runs as normal.  I personally don't like having to do this sort of thing but sometimes it is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Create a click event, so its function will only be triggered when clicking.

```
$("#this-box").click(function () {
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```